# RequestHeader of ServerCallContext is null in test cases

Tags: c#, nunit, grpc-c#

I have recently implemented gRPC service. I started writing test cases for that.
I have created a mock object on ServerCallContext object Mock.
Now I want to test my endpoint by passing the username. The username will get from ServerCallContext's RequestHeader. But in my Nunit test case, RequestHeader is null.
How to get RequestHeader. any reference to implement would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `Gprc.Core.Testing` library contains a [TestServerCallContext](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/csharp/api/Grpc.Core.Testing.TestServerCallContext.html) class in which a `ServerCallContext` can be mocked, including the metadata. Example where the username is passed in the metadata:

```
var metadata = new Metadata
{
    { "username", "Joe Johnson" }
};

var context = TestServerCallContext.Create("fooMethod", null,
 DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1), metadata, ...);
```

Using this test context in the tests you should be able to get the metadata from the  ServerCallContext's RequestHeader in your test cases.